# How can I get all ListItem in ListBox?

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

Good day, everyone!
I use pywinauto to automation desktop application. And I need to receive all ListItems from ListBox.
Then I execute this code:

```
def common_list(list_control):
    state = list_control.element_info.enabled
    if state:
        automation_id = list_control.element_info.automation_id
        if 'ListBox' in automation_id:
            # list_of_item = list_control.children(control_type="ListItem")
            list_of_item = list_control.items()
        else:
            list_of_item = list_control.children()[1:]
        time.sleep(pause)
        return list_of_item
```

I receive only visible elements of a list (in my case, it is 14 elements, but there are 53 of them).
How can I receive ALL of them?

Comment: There might be virtualized items. It may involve custom properties. This is not exactly the same as invisible elements.

Comment: What tells Inspect.exe?

Comment: Thanks, @VasilyRyabov. Inspect.exe can't tell anything about element that hidden for now. When list is scrolled Inspect.exe shows information about this hidden elements.

Comment: Well, it's definitely virtualized items. Will post example for `explorer.exe` a bit later. Not sure it would work for you, but hope it would be easy to adjust.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @VasilyRyabov! I will wait for yout example. I done some workaround aka "костыль" but it's not best way.

Comment: This is my [workaround](https://pastebin.com/FgHdsgje)

Comment: OK, is it WinForms application? Can you provide the `automation_id` for this control type?

Comment: No, this is WPF. `automation_id` is `RulesListBox`. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried to prepare example for `explorer.exe` and figured out why it was incomplete. This is the reason: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/pywinauto/controls/uia_controls.py#L650 (we should know the number of items which seems infeasible in common case).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @VasilyRyabov! I will try this solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use `.item_texts()` method.
It will be something like this:

```
window['ListBox1'].item_texts()
```