# How to check if some specific text exists in an application/window with pywinauto?

Tags: python, pywinauto

I want to use `pywinauto` to check if some specific text exists in an application/window. I used the search engine "google" to search for "pywinauto check text" but did not find anything useful. Also, the [documentation](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) was not useful, as I do not know what methods I can use to check for text. Also the methods of the "dialog"

```
['WAIT_CRITERIA_MAP', '_WindowSpecification__check_all_conditions', '_WindowSpecification__get_ctrl', '_WindowSpecification__parse_wait_args', '_WindowSpecification__resolve_control', '__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_ctrl_identifiers', 'actions', 'allow_magic_lookup', 'app', 'backend', 'child_window', 'criteria', 'dump_tree', 'exists', 'print_control_identifiers', 'print_ctrl_ids', 'wait', 'wait_not', 'window', 'wrapper_object']
```

do not show something obvious to check for some text.

So how can I check for some specific text in an application/window?

I get the corresponding window(?) using the following code:

```
dialog = Desktop(backend="uia")["MyProgram"]
if not dialog.exists():
    dialog = Application(backend='uia').start(path, timeout=300)["MyProgram"]
    dialog.wait("exists enabled visible ready")
dialog.set_focus()
```

It seems that the text I want to look for is in a pane(?):

```
x = dialog["SZRCPane10"]
```

and here I tried (following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136194/how-can-i-get-all-listitem-in-listbox)):

```
x.item_texts()
x["ListBox"].item_texts()
x["ListBox1"].item_texts()
x.ListBox.item_texts()
x.texts()
```

but none of them did work. When doing

```
print(x.print_control_identifiers())
```

I get the output

```
Pane - ''    (L413, T818, R1723, B1052)
['Pane']
child_window(auto_id="2362796", control_type="Pane")
   |
   | ListBox - '02.05.2023 08:17:08 - The Configuration Backend has just established connection to MPData'    (L413, T818, R1723, B1052)
   | ['02.05.2023 08:17:08 - The Configuration Backend has just established connection to MPData', 'ListBox', '02.05.2023 08:17:08 - The Configuration Backend has just established connection to MPDataListBox']
   | child_window(title="02.05.2023 08:17:08 - The Configuration Backend has just established connection to MPData", auto_id="listBoxMessages", control_type="List")
   |    |
   |    | ScrollBar - 'Vertical'    (L1705, T819, R1722, B1051)
   |    | ['VerticalScrollBar', 'ScrollBar', 'Vertical']
   |    | child_window(title="Vertical", auto_id="5051336", control_type="ScrollBar")
   ...
```

Is there a way to access these elements/controls?

Comment: Can you share application screenshot?

Comment: I am not sure I can do that. But when I do` x.print_control_identifiers()` I see the text printed out in the terminal as part of a ListBox (?). So maybe I redirect the print output into a variable and then check if the text is contained in there? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for text in your application first try to find the element/dialog/window the text belongs to. You can do that by running the method `print_control_identifiers()` on your dialog.

Once you have found the element you can select it e.g. by using

```
element = dialog["MyPane"]
```

and to check if some text `expected` is in that window you can do that as follows:

```
from io import StringIO
buffer = StringIO()
sys.stdout = buffer
element.print_control_identifiers()
print_output = buffer.getvalue()
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
if expected in print_output:
    print("Expected text has been found")
else:
    print("Text has not been found")
```

In that code you divert the output from `print_control_identifiers()` to a `StringIO` buffer you can check afterwards.